# Adding a inner border bottom to a subclass of UiView in swift4

Tags: uiview, uikit, swift4, ios11, xcode9

I want to add an inner border bottom to one of the subclass(custom) of UIView , I am looking if there is an extension for the UIview . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extension UIView {
    func customBorder(){
        let borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.84
        self.frame = frame.insetBy(dx: -borderWidth, dy: -borderWidth)
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Comment: CGRectInset is replaced by CGRect.insetBy method in swift4 . what to do?

Comment: @kamalakshihegde Check updated answer. You can also convert objective C code to swift [online.](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/)